# How to make a silent installation out of nested .exe InstallShields?

Tags: installation, installshield

I am trying to make a silent installation of an application that is using InstallShield.
When i am facing an InstallShield, i always use the record method to create a response file but i am crossing a problem.

The problem is that within the InstallShield, it will call another one and the record method won't work because it is out of scope (That's what i think).

How can i make a silent installation within that case? Do you have any ideas?

PS: I tried to display all the switches but it doesn't give me any response with: /?, --help, /HELP

I tried to create a log file but it won't work because the first installation won't end before the nested is done.

Thanks a lot for the support !

Create a repsonse file with the record method.